Keycloak-backed Spring Boot authentication: too many redirects
Please note: I know this question sounds similar to this one, however in that question, the issue was resolved by tailing the Keycloak logs, whereby the individual noticed a CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR error which ultimately led to their accepted solution. In my case, after reproducing the issue and tailing the Keycloak logs, no such error is produced, and so I believe this is simply a different root problem that bubbles to the surface with a similar "too many redirects" issue.

Spring Boot 3.X and Spring Security 6.X here, trying to use Key Cloak to handle all of my app's auth. As a successful first milestone, I'm trying to create a user in Key Cloak (including setting their password right there inside Keycloak), and then wire my Spring Boot/Security app to redirect to the Key Cloak login screen when trying to access authenticated URLs.
First, I have a Spring Boot app with a FizzWebController method like so:
@Controller
public class FizzWebController {

    private FizzService fizzService;

    @Autowired
    public FizzWebController(FizzService fizzService) {
        this.fizzService = fizzService;
    }

    @GetMapping("fizzes/home")
    public String fizzesHome(Model model) {

        List<FizzDTO> allFizzes = fizzService.getAllFizzes().stream()
            .map(fizz -> {

                FizzDTO fizzDTO = new FizzDTO();
                fizzDTO.setRefId(fizz.getRefId());
                fizzDTO.setBuzz(fizz.getBuzz());
                fizzDTO.setQuantity(fizz.getQuantity());

                return fizzDTO;

            })
            .toList();

        model.addAttribute("fizzList", allFizzes);

        return "fizzes";

    }

}

I can confirm that my app starts up just fine.
I then got the Key Cloak web + postgres containers running and am able to login to Key Cloak using the admin username + password that I set, and then subsequently, create a realm, a client for my app and a user:


All is well up to this point.
I add all of the following libraries to my build.gradle:
,"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
,"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client"
,"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server"

In application.properties I set:
# web/server/rest
server.error.path=/error
server.port=9200
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=myapp-client-dev
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=${OAUTH2_ISSUER_URI:http://localhost:8080/realms/myapp-realm-dev}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${OAUTH2_ISSUER_URI:http://localhost:8080/realms/myapp-realm-dev}

And then I create a Spring Security filter chain configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class FilterChainConfig {

    private static final String GROUPS = "groups";
    private static final String REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM = "realm_access";
    private static final String ROLES_CLAIM = "roles";

    private boolean debugEnabled;
    private KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    @Autowired
    public FilterChainConfig(
            @Value("${security.debugEnabled}") boolean debugEnabled,
            KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
        this.debugEnabled = debugEnabled;
        this.jwtValidationFilter = jwtValidationFilter;
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout(logout -> logout.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/users/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/users/password/reset").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/users/password").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapperForKeycloak() {
        return authorities -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            var authority = authorities.iterator().next();
            boolean isOidc = authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority;

            if (isOidc) {
                var oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                var userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                if (userInfo.hasClaim(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM)) {
                    var realmAccess = userInfo.getClaimAsMap(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM);
                    var roles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.get(ROLES_CLAIM);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                } else if (userInfo.hasClaim(GROUPS)) {
                    Collection<String> roles = userInfo.getClaim(
                            GROUPS);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }
            } else {
                var oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                if (userAttributes.containsKey(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM)) {
                    Map<String, Object> realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) userAttributes.get(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM);
                    Collection<String> roles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.get(ROLES_CLAIM);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }
            }
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }


    @Bean
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(Collection<String> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer debugSecurity() {
        return (web) -> web.debug(debugEnabled);
    }

}

I restart my app, and it starts up just fine. I open my browser to http://localhost:9200/fizzes/home and I get successfully redirected to the Keycloak Login screen!

However, as soon as I login, it first redirects my browser to:

Too many redirects?! Hmmm...
Then after maybe ~30 seconds it redirects my browser to:

I am 100% confident that I am entering the correct username + password for my user.
So I feel like I'm at least partially integrated with Keycloak, there just seems to be something missing, and I'm not sure what that is. I almost feel like: (1) something is misconfigured, so (2) too many redirects are occurring between Keycloak and my app, and eventually an error is hit and it brings me to some (3) Keycloak-provided error page. Plausible?
Important: when I go through this whole flow while tailing the Keycloak logs, I don't see the logs move at all and there are certainly no errors or stacktraces thrown.
Am I missing some configuration(s) on the Keycloak side? I would have expected it to authenticate me and redirect me to http://localhost:9200/fizzes/home. Do I need to add or change any configurations in Spring Security?
Update
Here's the bottom of my SS debug logs after the redirect fails per above:
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


whats the reason for not enabling your debug logs and reading them?

What you posted is not a log output. All you posted was a filter list. I suggest that you enable debug logs and read your logs as your redirect circle should be there and the reason and if posting logs you should understand that developers need to context, so a single thing from a log says nothing.

What I pasted was part of the debug logs, but I will post the full debug logs later this evening.

Remove .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())) and .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)). Also change redirct URL from http://ocalhost:9200/* to http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/keycloak.

Show your network tab in your dev tool of your browser (F12). Also show your Spring Security DEBUG logs.

Thanks @dur (+1 for both) -- I will post the DEBUG logs this evening when I am home. In the meantime, can you verify what you mean when you say "Also change redirct URL from http://ocalhost:9200/* to..."? Do you mean you want me to change the "Valid Redirect URIs" field in Keycloak to that new value, or do you mean something else? Thanks again!

in addition to removing oauth2ResourceServer as @Dur advised, you should also remove the dependency on spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server. You should also re-activate CSRF protection (with oauth2Login, security is based on sessions which are the vector for CSRF attacks). Regarding your problem, check the network tab of your browser debugging tool. You probably need to fix some access control for the callback to your Spring app with authorization-code

OK @ch4mp when I remove the dependency on spring-boot-start-oauth2-resource-server I get startup errors: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8080/realms/myapp-realm-dev"
which you'll notice is one of the properties I set in application.properties. Should I remove that property from application.properties as well (if so, just curious, why?) or should I do something else?
